# MvcContrib ShouldMapTo TestHelper throws AssertionException unexpectedly

Tags: mvccontrib

I'm getting an expected error with my route testing using MvcContrib's ShouldMapTo function.  According to the results, everything is fine, but the helper throws an AssertionException with an unfortunately sparse message. I'm using MVC1 and the corresponding MvcContirb.

```
[Test]
public void ThisShouldNotErrorButItDoes()
{
    "~/District/ParticipantInfo/1907/2010".Route().Values.ToList().ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Key + ": " + r.Value));
    Console.WriteLine(((Route)"~/District/ParticipantInfo/1907/2010".Route().Route).Url);
    "~/District/ParticipantInfo/1907/2010".ShouldMapTo<DistrictController>(c => c.ParticipantInfo(1907, 2010));
}
```

The first two lines show that the exception should not be thrown.  I'm mapping the correct controller, action, districtNumber, and surveyYear to match the correct route of {controller}/{action}/{districtNumber}/{surveyYear}.

My routes:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Participation",
            "{controller}/{action}/{districtNumber}/{surveyYear}",
            new { controller = "District", action = "ParticipantInfo" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                                          // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                                       // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = string.Empty });  // Parameter defaults
    }
```

The Error I'm getting is MvcContrib.TestHelper.AssertionException : Value for parameter did not match.

I've tracked this down to:  public static RouteData ShouldMapTo(this RouteData routeData, Expression> action)
            where TController : Controller
Which is inside of RouteTestingExtensions.cs

Does anyone have any clue on this one?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have already worked something out but there might be some others who are landing on this question and not getting any help. So I thought I will give a try to give some info about the issue.

I have to admit that I have tangled with this issue myself.
Please let me to refer to another forum for some insight.

Jonathan McCracken (the author of "Test-Drive ASP.NET MVC", which I like very much):

> MVC Contrib does not map parameters, that’s up to model binding which can be tested separately. So in these cases where you have parameters you need to pass null and then your test will pass.
>
> Here is the solution:

```
[TestFixture]
public class RouteDefinitionsTest
{
    [SetUp]
    public void setup()
    {
        var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
        routes.Clear();
        RouteDefinitions.AddRoutes(routes);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_Route_To_Edit_Page_With_Title()
    {            
        "~/Todo/Edit".
        ShouldMapTo<TodoController>(x => x.Edit(null));
    }
}
```

> Course you’ll need to add RouteDefinitions to your Web project as well which is here:

```
public class RouteDefinitions
{
    public static void AddRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
                        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = string.Empty} // Parameter defaults
            );
    }
}
```

> I just extracted this out of the Global.asax.cs file, so now that needs to change to the following:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        RouteDefinitions.AddRoutes(routes);
    }
```

Source (July 21, 2010): http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/124/topics/4824

If you care about the internal workings of the "ShouldMapTo()" then here is the source. Knock yourself out.

```
    public static RouteData ShouldMapTo<TController>(this RouteData routeData, Expression<Func<TController, ActionResult>> action)
        where TController : Controller
    {
        Assert.That(routeData, Is.Not.Null, "The URL did not match any route");

        //check controller
        routeData.ShouldMapTo<TController>();

        //check action
        var methodCall = (MethodCallExpression) action.Body;
        string actualAction = routeData.Values.GetValue("action").ToString();
        string expectedAction = methodCall.Method.Name;
        actualAction.AssertSameStringAs(expectedAction);

        //check parameters
        for (int i = 0; i < methodCall.Arguments.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = methodCall.Method.GetParameters()[i].Name;
            object value = ((ConstantExpression) methodCall.Arguments[i]).Value;

            Assert.That(routeData.Values.GetValue(name), Is.EqualTo(value.ToString()));
        }

        return routeData;
    }
```

Source (November 25, 2008): http://flux88.com/blog/fluent-route-testing-in-asp-net-mvc/ (it might be a bit out dated)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'd forgotten about this one.  The final answer was that once we downloaded source code for MvcContrib and linked to the source rather than the binaries, the error was no longer thrown.  We figured it must have been some strange bug in that version of the .dll which we were using, so we started using a newer release of MvcContrib.dll